# How to update data in datagridview?

Tags: c#, datagridview

```
                   OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection();

           conn.ConnectionString =
                  "Dsn=mdc;" +
                  "Uid=root;" +
                  "Pwd=;";


           OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("UPDATE tbl_delivery SET (Supplier, InvoiceNumber, DRNumber, PONumber, ItemQty, ReceivedDate, Address, Contact, ReceivedBy, AssetNumber) (Supplier ='" + this.supplierTextBox.Text + "',InvoiceNumber ='" + this.invoiceNumberTextBox.Text + "',DRNumber ='" + this.dRNumberTextBox.Text + "',PONumber ='" + this.pONumberTextBox.Text + "',ItemQty ='" + this.itemQtyTextBox.Text + "',ReceivedDate ='" + this.receivedDateDateTimePicker.Text + "',Address ='" + this.addressTextBox.Text + "',Contact ='" + this.contactTextBox.Text + "',ReceivedBy ='" + this.receivedByTextBox.Text + "',AssetNumber ='" + this.assetNumberTextBox.Text + "'", conn);

              cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            OdbcDataAdapter ds = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd);

             ds.SelectCommand = cmd;

            System.Data.DataTable dtable = new System.Data.DataTable();

             ds.Fill(dtable);

            tbl_deliveryDataGridView.DataSource = dtable;
             conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

**update button won't work, please check if my update statement is correct. i am using c#..............**

Comment: Windows forms or ASP.NET ?

Comment: It is recommended to use OdbcCommand Parameters in the update query. @Partha `datagridview` is in Windows Form.

Comment: It's hard to see anything past the SQL injection.

Comment: And your update doesnt have a where clause. Are you sure you want to update the entire table ?

Comment: Pls refer this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233819(v=VS.90).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think your Query is incorrect.

```
  OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection();

       conn.ConnectionString =
              "Dsn=mdc;" +
              "Uid=root;" +
              "Pwd=;";


       OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("UPDATE tbl_delivery SET Supplier ='" + this.supplierTextBox.Text + "',InvoiceNumber ='" + this.invoiceNumberTextBox.Text + "',DRNumber ='" + this.dRNumberTextBox.Text + "',PONumber ='" + this.pONumberTextBox.Text + "',ItemQty ='" + this.itemQtyTextBox.Text + "',ReceivedDate ='" + this.receivedDateDateTimePicker.Text + "',Address ='" + this.addressTextBox.Text + "',Contact ='" + this.contactTextBox.Text + "',ReceivedBy ='" + this.receivedByTextBox.Text + "',AssetNumber ='" + this.assetNumberTextBox.Text + "'", conn);
```

Then where is your **Where clause? just add it on the query**
Then

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
ds= newodbcDataAdapter(cmd);
ds.Fill(dtable);
tbl_deliveryDataGridView.ItemsSource = dtable.DefaultView;
```

You better execute your query first before displaying it to your datagrid for that you'll able to see the updated table.